# How to delay trigger creation in Node.js using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, triggers, sequelize.js

I'm having problems in creating a trigger using Node.js + Express + Sequelize.

I have tables for my model objects (i.e. User, Device, ...) and join tables to express their Many-to-Many associations (i.e. hasDevice).

My troubles come from my inability in creating a simple trigger with a

```
sequelize.query('query', null, {raw: true});
```

since tables creation is totally asynchronous and I cannot know when trigger's table will be created (In particular I'm getting the following error:

> Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table
>   'express612.hasDevice' doesn't exist

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to run the trigger that creates the query after the tables are created.  What is the code that asynchronously creates the tables?

Comment: That is my problem indeed. I don't feel like I have control over table creation process. I'm following this tutorial http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express#the-application and, as you can see, there's no explicit section regarding table creation (or maybe it's just me being a little newbie on this matter)

Comment: Seems like it would be in the `.then` callback after `.sync`

Comment: You were goddamn right :) In particular, according to Sequelize's official tutorial, sync() is used inside ./bin/www (and that's why I wasn't seeing it). @ExplosionPills you can write an answer to receive the green tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are created asynchronously, so you need to do any work that relies on the creation of the tables (such as trigger creation) in the callback after tables are created.  According to the documentation, this seems to be after the `.sync` method, for example:

http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express#the-application

You can create the trigger in the callback to `.sync().then`